# Having trouble wrapping my head around complex $group'ing/aggregation

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a schema that is something like this:

```
{
  _id: <objectid>
  customer: <objectid>
  employee: <objectid>
  date: <Month/day/year>
  amount: <Number>
}
```

Using angular, I'm trying to make a page that pulls that data and builds separate tables for each day.   So something like I would have a tab for yesterday, that would open up a view for a table that has all of my employees listed and the sum of their  for the day.  Something like this:

```
[{
  date: 10/29/2019
  dataFromThisDate: [
    {
      employee: <name>
      sumAmount: <sum(amount for this date)>
      list:  [<array of all of the transaction _ids 
    },
    {
      employee: <name 2> 
      //etc
    }]
 },
 {
   date: 10/30/2019
   dataFromThisDate: //etc
 }]
```

Basically as far as I've gotten is just:

```
MyCollection.aggregate(
  [{
    $group: {
       _id: "$date"
    }
  }],function(err, result) { //blah }
)
```

But I'm not sure how to even do nested grouping (first by date, then by employee on that date).  Just thinking through it, it feels like I would have to group by date, then pass on all the data to a new grouping pipeline?

Sorry I don't have more of what I've tried, this whole aggregation thing is just completely new to me and I can't find good examples that are similar enough to what I'm trying to do to learn from.  I looked at the api docs for mongodb and I understand their basic examples and play around with them, but I'm just having a hard time coming up with how to do my more complex example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. This uses two groups. First group by date and employee, summing the amount and adding the transaction ids. Second group by date and add the employees with their total amount and transactions list.

```
aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            date: "$date",
            employee: "$employee"
        },
        amount: {
            $sum: "$amount"
        },
        transactionIds: {
            $push: "$_id"
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id.date",
        dataFromThisDate: {
            $push: {
                employee: "$_id.employee",
                sumAmount: "$amount",
                list: "$transactionIds"
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

Output

```
 {
    "_id": "12/21/2016",
    "dataFromThisDate": [{
        "employee": "employee1",
        "sumAmount": 100,
        "list": [ObjectId("58151e881ac3c9ce82782663")]
    }, {
        "employee": "employee2",
        "sumAmount": 73,
        "list": [ObjectId("58151e881ac3c9ce82782665"), ObjectId("58151e881ac3c9ce82782666")]
    }]
 }
```

Comment: Thank you!  Sorry it took so long to get back to this, but that worked beautifully!